# How to access data inside nested loop in Handlebars?

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

I have data as follows where `keyPairs` is dynamic columns of a table and `data` has the row data.

```
keyPairs: {
"key0":"Value0",
"key1":"Value1",
    ...
}

data:[
{
"name":"name0",
"key0":"Value0",
"key1":"---",
},

{
"name":"name1",
"key0":"---",
"key1":"Value1",
}]
```

The `keyPairs` object is dynamically created, and the keys used in each object in the `data` array are the same as the keys in `keyPairs`. I am unable get the values for each `data` item with each `@key` from `keyPairs`.

```
{{#each data as | row |}}
    <td>
        {{row.name}}
    </td>

{{#each ../keyPairs}}
    <td>
        {{./row[@key]}}
    </td>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems.

First, you are trying to step-up a context-level from within your `#each` using `./row`. However, the correct syntax for this is two dots, `../row`.

Secondly, when you step-up a context-level, by using `../row` you are trying to access a `row` property on the parent context. But the parent does not *have* a `row` property because the parent *is* the `row` object. So the correct reference would be `..` instead of `../row`.

Third, Handlebars does not support dynamic key evaluation with square brackets. You need to use the [lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) to do this evaluation, `{{lookup .. @key}}`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ej9un5f3/) for your reference.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I had already done with it by self with some hit and trials.

Comment: @SahyogVishwakarma: That's great! For the future, I would recommend posting your solution so that those with the same issue can learn from it and potential responders will know you no longer need their help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thanks [@76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484) for your answer.
Second I had got my answer on my own, and its quite similar to answer given by him.
I achieved the solution to my question with the following syntax.

```
{{#each data as | row |}}
    <td>
        {{row.name}}
    </td>

{{#each ../keyPairs}}
    <td>
        {{lookup row @key}}
    </td>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```